# What change does the OS need to make, given this message? "iCloud Preferences wants to make changes to your account"

Tags: macos, security, system-settings

This message appears when I log on to my machine. It doesn't tell me what change it wants to make, so I deny it access to my system.

Does anyone know what change it is trying to make?

[image: System Preferences: iCloud Preferences wants to make changes to your account. Type your password to allow this.]

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to set up the iCloud account as a trusted authentication platform for your local user account. This is usually for a feature such as the Apple Watch unlock, whereby the Apple Watch can unlock your local account through iCloud.

Comment: Thank you. Seems unsafe to ask for your password without explicitly stating the reason though.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the answer given above by 'grg': In other words, it seems that this would appear to be granting iCloud the ability to be authenticated to access my local user account -- and make changes to application data on my system -- whenever my system is booted up and establishing a connection to iCloud.  I have heard some horror stories about iCloud reorganizing and deleting items from iTunes or iPhoto libraries. This does not inspire confidence in allowing iCloud to be a 'trusted authentication platform' for my local account !